# C# - simple property usage example form tutorial doesn't work

Tags: c#, properties

As a beginner in C# I'm looking for useful tutorials in internet. I came across this one: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/ . I found supposedly easy example of property usage that gives unexpected result (I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015). The example is taken from lesson http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/properties/ and a previous lesson.

```
using System;
namespace Workshop
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car;

            car = new Car("Red");
            Console.WriteLine(car.Describe());

            car = new Car("Green");
            Console.WriteLine(car.Describe());

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        private string color;

        public Car(string color)
        {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public string Describe()
        {
            return "This car is " + Color;
        }

    public string Color
    {
        get
        {
            return color.ToUpper();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == "Red")
                color = value;
            else
                Console.WriteLine("This car can only be red!");
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this program is:

```
The car is RED
The car is GREEN
```

while I expected that the second line would be:

```
This car can only be red!
```

Can someone explain to me why this example behave like this?
And more general question: does anyone know if this tutorial is a good one, or should I look for something different?

Comment: the second line is in the set method of the property. so it will output `This car can only be red` only when you **set** the color anything other than red.

Comment: You never set the field from the property, try `this.Color = color`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line is in the set method of `Color` property.
In your code, you didn't call the set method of Color. 
If you want this line, edit your constructor :

```
public Car(string color)
{
   this.Color = color;
}
```

However, you don't set `color` when the string is not "Red". So, the output will be :

```
The car is RED
This car can only be red!
```

And after that, you'll get a NullReferenceException because `color` is null in `return color.ToUpper();`

Answer (score 1):

You have set `color` (variable) in the constructor , so no validation happened because you have placed validation in `set{}` of `Color`(property).
So because you are not setting `Color`,it never hits the setter.